# vue v-bind:class return invalid value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am writing an application at vue and I am getting incorrect behavior, in particular my line :class=require ? 'require' : '' returns the string 'require' even when the value of require is false, what is the problem?

```html
<template>
  <custom-label label="Название">
    <input
        class="text_input"
        :class="require ? 'require' : ''"
        :value="$attrs.value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
        placeholder="Матрица всея барановичского района"
    />
  </custom-label>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "InputText",
  components: {CustomLabel},
  computed: mapState({ state: state => state }),
  props: {
    require: Boolean
  }
};
</script>
```

Below are screenshots from devtools

[image: HTML]

[image: vue dev-tools]

Comment: What if you try `:class="[require && 'require']"`?

Comment: I tried :class="{ require }" and  :class="{ require: require }", and right now I tried :class="[require && 'require']" I got same result

Comment: What if you try to toggle the boolean? Can you see the actual class being triggered? Are you sure there is nothing else interfering with your state? Do you have a [repro]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent 3 hours on this before writing the question on StackOverflow. As soon as I published the question, after a few minutes I realized that I have a require function in the global area, which is needed for example for images

```
<img :src="require('./img.png')" />
```

this is a very stupid mistake, but I hope someone who also encounters it will be able to avoid it with the help of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:class="{ require }"` instead.

Comment: This will not print `'require'` as far as I know, since `require` is a Boolean and not a `'require'` string.

Comment: @kissu Vue will automatically translate it into a string. See https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes

Comment: Hm indeed, didn't that one. Vue3 addition I guess?